# Find ksh functions using nodejs regex

Tags: node.js, regex

I want to write some regex which matches the following: any char regargless how often and then and opening and closing bracket. Also I don't want it to match if there is a # infront of it.
Here is what I tried so far:

`\s*^(?!#)*[A-Za-z0-9_]*\(\)`

The problem is that this regex seems to match every line in the test file, not just the functions that I want.

Have a great day

EDIT:

```
function match(array, regex) {//Rematcher
    back = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let line = array[i];
        if (regex.test(line)) {
            back.push(line);
        }
    }
    return back
}


function find(text) {//function finder

    let reg = new RegExp("^(?!#)*\w*\(\)");

    return reMatcher.match(text, reg);

}




let content = fs.readFileSync(file, "UTF-8");//starting point

let functions = find_functions.find(content);

content = content.split("\n");
```

//Testfile

meldet()

{
 if true

then

if true

then

echo Pseudocode

fi

echo Pseudocode

fi

}

The regex should only match the first line, but instead it matches every line and also it shouldn't match on lines where a # is before the function header

Comment: It could not match `#` as it is not in the character class `^\w*\(\)` https://regex101.com/r/aAmbDu/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird while this works online, it doesn't seem to work local in nodejs

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you are using that does not work for you?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I've updated the question, i hope this is enough

Comment: Try it like this `let reg = new RegExp("^\\w*\\(\\)", 'g');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pattern `\s*^(?!#)*[A-Za-z0-9_]*\(\)` you can omit the `\s*` before the start of the line anchors.

As you don't match a `#` in the character class, you can also omit the negative lookahead `(?!#)`

---

Instead of using `reMatcher.match(text, reg);`, you could use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on the `text` variable.

Note to double escape the backslashes in the RegExp constructor.

You could update the function find to:

```
function find(text) {
    let reg = new RegExp("\\s*^(?!#)*[A-Za-z0-9_]*\\(\\)");
    return text.match(reg)[0]; // Or first check the value before indexing
}
```

Comment: text is an array and i need to do the same in mutiple modules so I thought it was a good idea to make it a micro module. And also that regex works!!! It looks like i only need to escape the escaps, so big thanks to you, you really helped me out